# Icons not shown while using Bundling

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, stylebundle

I am using Bundling for my CSS and use that in my MVC `Layout.cshtml` page. The CSS files are included correctly but the icons are not shown properly.

Should i do something to include icons?

**MY Bundle code**

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/Site.css",
            "~/Content/ej/web/ej.widgets.core.min.css",
            "~/Content/ej/web/default-theme/ej.theme.min.css",
            "~/Content/TodoList.css"));
```

I am using it in my page as follow

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

But i am getting as follow.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Madhu

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use [CssRewriteUrlTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.cssrewriteurltransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Rewrites urls to be absolute so assets will still be found after bundling.

Your code might look something like

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
    .Include("~/Content/Site.css")
    .Include("~/Content/ej/web/ej.widgets.core.min.css",
        new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    .Include("~/Content/ej/web/default-theme/ej.theme.min.css",
        new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    .Include("~/Content/TodoList.css"));
```

Comment: Thanks but i cant find the `CssRewriteUrlTransform` in `System.Web.Optimization`? Where could i find it?

Comment: Make sure you have the [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/).

Answer (score 0):

Specify normal .css files. .Net will automatically pick .min.css files in Release Mode. Make sure both .css and .min.css have Image urls.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/Site.css",
            "~/Content/ej/web/ej.widgets.core.css",
            "~/Content/ej/web/default-theme/ej.theme.css",
            "~/Content/TodoList.css"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason and the solution for my issue. I provided the virtual path incorrectly. I changed it as follow and now its working fine.

```
 // Content css
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/Site.css")              
            .Include("~/Content/TodoList.css"));

 // Content ej css
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/ej/web/css")
        .Include("~/Content/ej/web/ej.widgets.core.min.css")
        .Include("~/Content/ej/web/default-theme/ej.theme.min.css"));
```